# articles that explain Conway's game of life

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics, game-theory

For a few days I have been studying the game of life, I would like to understand it better from a mathematical point of view. I am looking for an article that talks about it without neglecting the mathematical reasons why it is important and as accessible as possible to a student with only a basic knowledge of mathematics.
I write in search of advice,
good day to all readers!

Comment: @AntimatterHedgehog since the OP is explicitly asking for a reference request, your three comments are good enough for an answer on their own! I would delete them and repost them as your own answer. Please include a short description of the link and why it's helpful as you did in the comments.

Comment: @Hooked Done! Thank you for pointing this out! Still learning the site, so I always feel insecure about what counts as "usefull" answers, but I can see your argument makes sense.

Comment: @AntimatterHedgehog we were all new users at one point. The Stack Exchange sites can sometimes be off-putting for new users, so try to follow the lead of others when you ask or answer a question. If you really want to contribute, find a tag and try to read everything from that tag and answer those questions you feel qualified for. Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Davide, here is an equation for Conways game of life.

http://www.buzwordsalad.com/mfile/gol/conways_game_of_life.png

Here is the m-file to see how it works.

http://www.buzwordsalad.com/mfile/gol/gun_glider.m

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am also interested in the game of life and the more general concept of cellular automata. [This](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GameofLife.html) article served as a nice introduction for me. It is kinda short, and contains many references that you can follow.

If you are interested in the game of life, I would also recommend looking into the more general concept of cellular automata. One entry-point might be [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CellularAutomaton.html) brief article. It also contains references that you can follow.

By chance, I also stumbled upon [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3803725/%E2%80%A6) about cellular automata here on MSE. There you can see what references the experts on MSE recommend on the topic, and one of the links leads to a set of lecture notes which are available for free. Note that the lecture notes actually start out with discussing the game of life :)